# How to change font size at breakpoints bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a page title `<h1> MY JOB </h1>` with a font size of `70px`. I want to automatically change the size of the title to font size `36px` when the page reaches a small breakpoint (mobile phone).

How can I achieve this?

Here is what I have done so far:

```css
.title-extra-large-5 {
  font-size: 70px !important;
  line-height: 80px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .xs-title-extra-large-4{
    font-size: 36px !important;
    line-height: 42px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h2 class="title-extra-large-5 md-title-extra-large-3 xs-title-extra-large-4">MY JOB.</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you mention that your title is `h1`, but, in your example, you use `h2`.

Apart from that, you are on the right track. You just need to change couple of things:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 70px !important;
  line-height: 80px !important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  h2{
    font-size: 36px !important;
    line-height: 42px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8">
          <h2>MY JOB.</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You do not need to refer to `col-sm-12` and `col-xs-12` as bootstrap will render into them by default. And you do not need to have extra classes `title-extra-large-5 md-title-extra-large-3 xs-title-extra-large-4` you can just refer to `h2` or `h1`.

Comment: hi I did that bcoz h2 is used in multiple titles, your method works perfectly this is what I needed, thank you

Comment: @JeffersonXMasonic if my answer solves your problem, please accept it. Here is a guide on how to accept an answer on StackOverflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/319051

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by certain screen size, you want to change it, right?

**ACCORDING TO W3SCHOOLS.COM**

You can use the @media property to display a certain set of styles in a certain situation.

```
body{
    background-color: blue; /*For screens with more than 480px screen width.*/
}
p{
    font-size:72px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { /*Same but for less*/
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
    p{
        font-size:36px;
    }
}
```

Comparing this to your code, I'd say you've got it mostly correct, but be leniant on *!important*. This can conflict with other styles, so only use it when you do **NOT** want it to change, or the style won't be applied otherwise.
**EDIT:** It seems you have two classes which do the exact same thing, but conflict with each other due to *!important*. I'd say just keep one of the classes and change the styles with `@media` so you're gauranteed it'll work and that it won't conflict with other styles.